# SSL context array of keymanagers/trustmanagers

Tags: java, ssl

Why does SSLContext accept an array of keymanagers/trustmanagers when in javadoc it is stated that "Only the first instance of a particular key and/or trust manager implementation type in the array is used. (For example, only the first javax.net.ssl.X509KeyManager in the array will be used.)"? (why ask for an array when you actually need only one object?)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't 'actually need only one object'. It actually needs only one object 'of a particular key and/or trust manager implementation type'. Read it again. You can't supply two X509KeyManagers for example, as it says, but you can supply any number of *different* KeyManagers.